# How to verify if a specific function is called

Tags: go, mocking, stubbing

I'm trying my hand at writing TDD in Go. I am however stuck at the following.

The test to write:

```
func TestFeatureStart(t *testing.T) {}
```

Implementation to test:

```
func (f *Feature) Start() error {
  cmd := exec.Command(f.Cmd)
  cmd.Start()
}
```

How would one test this simple bit? I figured I only wanted to verify that the exec library is spoken to correctly. That's the way I would do it in Java using Mockito. Can anyone help me write this test? From what I've read the usage of interfaces is suggested.

The Feature-struct only contains a string Cmd.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can fake the whole deal with interfaces, but you could also use fakeable functions. In the code:

```
var cmdStart = (*exec.Cmd).Start
func (f *Feature) Start() error {
    cmd := exec.Command(f.Cmd)
    return cmdStart(cmd)
}
```

In the tests:

```
called := false
cmdStart = func(*exec.Cmd) error { called = true; return nil }
f.Start()
if !called {
    t.Errorf("command didn't start")
}
```

See also: Andrew Gerrand's [Testing Techniques talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ndmB0bj7eyw).

Comment: If this is used inside go routines, or your function will be called in a go routine, it'll have data race condition. Just saying so it might help someone else.